# Pandas / Dask Reading a semi-tabular text

Tags: pandas, dataframe, parsing, dask

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
Version:23
Developer: Ali

NAME AGE IN
- Carol 22 no
- Kyle 31 yes
...
```

I ma reading it using Dask dataframe (which should be similar to Pandas). The result table should be dataframe look like this:

```
NAME AGE IN
Carol 22 no
Kyle 31 yes
```

I am having trouble to get rid of **the dash in each row** ('-') below the column name '-'. I tried

```
dd.read_csv(filepath, header = 3, sep="\s+")
```

which results in a dataframe with has different row size and brings more problems,
and I also tried using multiple delimiters but still giving errors.

```
dd.read_csv(filepath, header = 3, sep="\s-\s+")
```

Answer (score 0):

`dask.dataframe` assumes your data is already in a tabular format. If you insist on using dask, then you will get further with `dask.bag`, which will load the file line by line. You can then filter out the lines that do not start with a dash, and process the ones that do, encoding them as a json object/dict, which you later convert to dataframe with `.to_dataframe()`.